# Ambiguous occurrence of == when creating a type as an instance of Eq

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading

From *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good*:

```
class Eq1 a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
    (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x == y = not (x /= y)
    x /= y = not (x == y)

data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green

instance Eq1 TrafficLight where
    Red == Red = True
    Green == Green = True
    Yellow == Yellow = True
    _ == _ = False
```

When I load this into `ghci`, I got an error:

```
baby.hs:213:9:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘==’
    It could refer to either ‘Main.==’, defined at baby.hs:225:5
                          or ‘Prelude.==’,
                             imported from ‘Prelude’ at baby.hs:1:1
                             (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Classes’)
```

As far as I understand, `==` here is specific to the `Trafficlight` type. Where is the ambiguity, here?

Comment: It's because Eq1 redefines ==. If you leave out all the Eq1 declaration and just use Eq which is defined for you in the Prelude (automatically imported), it'll work fine. If you want your own Eq1 for some reason, don't call it ==.

Comment: You can hide the `==` and `/=` that are defined in `Eq` in the standard prelude by adding an explicit `import` declaration for `Prelude` to the top of your file: `import Prelude hiding ((==), (/=))`. The extra `( )` around the operators change an infix operator into an ordinary symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is actually in `class Eq1`, not in `instance Eq1 Trafficlight`:

```
class Eq1 a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
    (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x == y = not (x /= y) -- which (/=) ?
    x /= y = not (x == y) -- which (==) ?
```

At that point it's not clear whether you want to use `Prelude.==` or `Main.==`. You need to make that clear:

```
class Eq1 a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
    (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x == y = not (x Main./= y)
    x /= y = not (x Main.== y)
```

Now `instance Eq1 Trafficlight` will work, since you're really defining the `(==)` and `(/=)` of your `Eq1` instance. However, keep in mind that `Red == Yellow` will still be ambiguous, since there are really two `(==)` and `(/=)` at hand. In order to fix this, you need to prefix all calls to `==` and `/=`.

Better use other names for your operators:

```
class Eq1 a where
   (===), (=/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
   x === y = not $ x =/= y
   x =/= y = not $ x === y
```